# golang: Как изменить нейминг стратегию sqlx?

Tags: sql, golang

Есть такое подключение

```
    db, err := sqlx.Connect(
        "postgres",
        fmt.Sprintf(
            "postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?sslmode=disable",
            databaseUser,
            databasePassword,
            databaseHost,
            databasePort,
            databaseDB,
        ),
    )
```

и такой метод

```
    type A struct {
        task string
        taskDone string 
    }
    a := A{}
    result, err := db.NamedExec(
        `INSERT INTO mcc (task, task_done) VALUES (:task, :taskdone)`,
        a,
    )
```

код работает. Но если я меняю `:taskdone` на `:task_done`, то выдает ошибку `could not find name task_done`

```
    db, err := sqlx.Connect(
        "postgres",
        fmt.Sprintf(
            "postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?sslmode=disable",
            databaseUser,
            databasePassword,
            databaseHost,
            databasePort,
            databaseDB,
        ),
    )
```

и такой метод

```
    type A struct {
        task string
        taskDone string 
    }
    a := A{}
    result, err := db.NamedExec(
        `INSERT INTO mcc (task, task_done) VALUES (:task, :task_done)`,
        a,
    )
```

С `select` аналогичная проблема.

Как сделать так, что бы работал вариант с `:task_done`?

Comment: taskDone string \`db:"task_done"\`

Comment: добавьте тэг на переменную структуры. подробнее об этом [тут](https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо! в Структуре нужно было добавить TaskDone uint `db:"task_done"`